# Save in GPU memory iOS device image in advance

Tags: ios, image, opengl-es

I have images for displaying in UICollectionView. I saved all my images in array, so I don't load it from disk or network.
When my image appears first time, device has some lag. But when this image appears later there is all ok. There is no problems with my code< and I don't want ask about it. I want understand can I load image to GPU memory in advance. So when image will be appear in first time on screen there is no lag, because this image (or maybe it is called texture) will be in memory cache and device will spend little time for drawing from memory.

So tell me is it possible without going deep in OpenGL, can I do it with CoreFramework?

Comment: if you're loading imagines with OpenGL for a Collection View you are doing it wrong. Never resort to OpenGL for pure image displaying.

Comment: What method and what object is used to load the image itself? If the image is cached (which seems to be the case) then all you need to do is load it when application is loading (or whenever you feel is a good time to do it) and it will be ready to use next time (The second load will grab it from cache). But you do need to understand that the system controlling the cache might remove the image from the cache at any time it feels it should which is usually on memory warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't find solution, but I load some UIImageViews with my images on start not in the frame of my viewcontroller view. And After this hack I have not problem with lag